# How do I skip to a position in the animation with an animationplayer in Godot?

Tags: animation, godot

I'm making a game in godot and have to store the animation position because the animation gets suspended by another one. I want to continue the animation where it was before and that's why I have to store the animation position and then set it to the stored value.

I've tried setting it (didn't work) and in the documentation and other places in the internet I haven't found anything helpful.

This is the script on it:

```
extends KinematicBody2D

onready var animation_player = $AnimationPlayer

var hurt_anim_playing: bool = false
var hurt_anim_progress: float = 0

func _ready():
    animation_player.play("idle")
    pass

func _physics_process(delta): 
    # for each touching heart, get hurt
    for body in hitbox.get_overlapping_bodies(): 
        if body.has_method("heart"):
            G.health -= 1
            hurt_anim_playing = true
            hurt_anim_progress = animation_player.current_animation_position
            animation_player.play("hurt")
            update_sprite()
            body.queue_free()


func die():
    dieLayer.visible = true 
    get_tree().paused = true

func update_sprite():
    sprite.frame = G.max_health - G.health 
    if G.health == 0:
        die()


func _on_AnimationPlayer_animation_finished(anim_name):
    if anim_name == "hurt":
        hurt_anim_playing = false 
        animation_player.play("idle")
        animation_player.current_animation_position = hurt_anim_progress
```

Actually I wanted to set the animation position and let the animation continue where it stopped, but instead I got an error

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `Invalid set index 'current_animation_position' (on base: 'AnimationPlayer') with value of type 'float'`

Comment: If it's looking for a float, have you tried declaring your hurt-animation variable as `var hurt_anim_progress: float = 0.0`?

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work, I think for what you're trying to do, another approach which might make things easier would be to use Coroutines -- yield() and resume()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that current_animation_position has only a getter, not a setter:
https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.1/classes/class_animationplayer.html#class-animationplayer-property-current-animation-position

To set the animation to a specific point, you can use advance(float delta), if you want to handle everything between start and the resuming point or seek(float seconds, bool update=false), if you just want to jump to the new position. You may test out, if you need to set update to true. The documentation says "If update is true, the animation updates too, otherwise it updates at process time."

Your code would simply look like this:

```
func _physics_process(delta): 
# for each touching heart, get hurt
for body in hitbox.get_overlapping_bodies(): 
    if body.has_method("heart"):
        G.health -= 1
        hurt_anim_playing = true
        hurt_anim_progress = animation_player.current_animation_position
        animation_player.play("hurt")
        update_sprite()
        body.queue_free()


func _on_AnimationPlayer_animation_finished(anim_name):
    if anim_name == "hurt":
        hurt_anim_playing = false 
        animation_player.play("idle")
        animation_player.seek(hurt_anim_progress) #maybe (hurt_anim_progress, true)
```